# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have read [StackQ1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097273/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment) and [stackQ2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873285/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-input-referenced-before-assignment) But unable to solve my error. 
The given below program is giving

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment

I already made variable `k` as `global` but it is not working.

```
class myClass:
    global k
    k=0
    def data(self):
        def data2(k):
                for j in range(5):
                    k=k+1
                    return k
        for i in range(5):
            k=k+1
            data2(k)

Obj = myClass()
print(Obj.data())
```

I also tried as

```
k=0
class myClass:
#     global k

    def data(self):
        def data2(k):
                for j in range(5):
                    k=k+1
                    return k
        for i in range(5):
            k=k+1
            data2(k)

Obj = myClass()
print(Obj.data())
```

But not working.

Comment: You should be doing `self.k`. Wonder why you need a nested function anyway

Comment: put the k var outside of the class (without global attr)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Wrong. It is not working.

Comment: @AriGold  Wrong. not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python local variable referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877649/python-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: Its says `UnboundLocalError` you need to call it through the class use `self.k`, and dont use global with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class My_Class(object):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(My_Class, self).__init__()
         self.k = "hello"
     def data(self, *args):
         print "call data"
         return self.k


my_class = My_Class()
print my_class.data()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved and posting it for the newbies

```
class myClass:
    k=0
    def data(self):
        def data2(k):
                for j in range(5):
                    self.k=self.k+1
                    return self.k
        for i in range(5):
            self.k=self.k+1
            data2(self.k)

Obj = myClass()
print(Obj.data())
```

Credit goes to @Moses Koledoye and @ Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

For my explanation, I reindent and annotate your code:

```
class myClass:  # <- [1]
    global k  # <- [2]
    k = 0  # <- [3]

    def data(self):
        def data2(k):  # <- [4]
            for j in range(5):
                k = k + 1
                return k  # <- [5]

        for i in range(5):
            k = k + 1  # <- [6]
            data2(k)


Obj = myClass()
print(Obj.data())
```

### Code Review

[1] Class names should use CamelCase according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) recommandation. Note that your class should inherit from `object` (in Python 2.7) to use (modern) new-style class.

[2] Global variable `k` is not defined at module level. You can't declare a variable in Python, you must define it. Since `k` looks like a integer, you can write:

```
k = 0
```

[3] Here, you define a class variable.

Python use [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#construction)
   to construct and initialize an class instance.
   You should use `__init__` method to initialise your class, as below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 0
```

[4] Here, you define a function inside the `data` method. What do you want to do? A new method?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def data(self):
        def data2(k):  # <- [4]
            pass
```

[5] I think you return prematurely: the loop ends at first iteration. Mind your indentation:

```
def data2(k):
    for j in range(5):
        k = k + 1
    return k  # <- [5]
```

[6] The local variable `k` is not defined in the `data` function.
If you want to use the module level variable (and modify it), you must use `global` keyword.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def data(self):
        global k
        for i in range(5):
            k = k + 1  # <- [6]
            data2(k)
```

Let’s start with a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).